# zooming out from a png deforms it

Tags: android, image, png, zooming

I have simple png image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0r3M.jpg) and when I zoom out, to <10% the image begins to deform and I am missing most of the outline. The zoom-out is for supporting multiple displays.

This image is actually used as a template for a collage and so it is in its "final" size, and I wish to keep it like so.

I tried to convert the image into a 9-patch, but it still shows the same behavior.

I've tried asking Google but without success... could you please advise?

Thanks

Comment: It's a pixel image, so *any* shrinking or enlarging is gong to affect the pixels. To make it smaller, you could use a filter. That way your 1-pixel black lines change into 1-pixel gray lines -- but that only works until the gray is so light you can't see it. Have you considered vector images instead? They have slightly different problems of their own, but it would work for your example.

Comment: Hi @Jongware, I have read in several places that android is not built for vector images, and also could not find much about how to use them.. could you please direct me to relevant info?

Comment: "Not built for vector" -- it doesn't *need* to be. You have a vector image in memory and a library to convert it to a bitmap -- that's resolution independent. You would typically create your bitmaps once for the "current" device, cache them, and then use only these bitmaps.

Comment: Could you please provide with some example/tutorial?

Comment: Code to "render" simple rectangles such as in your example image is trivial, but if you have more complicated images, Google for 'vector rendering library'. Locally saving the cached image as a compatible bitmap is something else--you'll have to look in the Android SDK for that.